# Run Classes priority wise in Nunit

Tags: c#

Can we prioritize our classes in NUnit? if yes then how we can prioritize them not the test cases i am talking about classes like in Testng in xml file which class is written at first place runs firstly can we do such a thing in NUnit?

Comment: What's the point for priorities? Test classes should be independent, as well as test cases.

Comment: I want to made my test classes prioritize so i can run it with my own priority